# Group Students on the Basis of Marks

Tags: java, algorithm

I am developing an application in java which suggests possible groups of students (two or three students per group) on the basis of the marks they obtain in various subjects. I would like to study similar algorithms before i devise my own.
For instance of there are a total of two courses and also two students per group than the algorithm should pair students up in groups in such a way that student a should be good in subject 1 whereas student b should be good in subject b.

**Detailed Explanantion:**
The input will be in this form:

```
student1<90.38<labs
Student1<93.01<exam
Student2<90.38<labs
Student2<85.20<exams
.         .       .
.         .       .         
.         .       .
.         .       .
Studentn<61.48<exams
```

The first part is the unique id of each student, the second part is marks obtained and the third part is the particular course component the marks have been obtained.

The algorithm should create groups of two of students which complement each other on the basis of marks obtained in each component, labs as well as exams.

Output should be somewhat like

```
student1|student13|
student17|student15|
student8|student10|
.               .
.               .
.               .
studentn|studentm|
```

where each line corresponds to a single group of two students.

Comment: so the second part is your sum of marks from exams/labs?

Comment: Second part?
If you mean Output by second part then no its the pairing of students into groups in terms of a good student paired with a bad student on the basis of marks obtained in both labs and exams which both are in turn assigned weights. This is just my solution to this problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED:
The pairing of students into groups is done in terms of a good student paired with a bad student on the basis of marks obtained in both labs and exams which both are in turn assigned weights. This is just my solution to this problem.

I have a C++ implementation of my solution, but before I go with incorporating it in my application, I want to study any alternative takes on this problem, hence this post.

Comment: OK by *"Showing your effort"*  I actually meant code, but as I carefully read the question again I think ..What exactly *is* your question?

Comment: The question was any theoretical solution to the above stated problem which  @tintinmj just did.

Comment: This is my source code of my solution.
[link](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1310)
 The input to this program is a txt file with a format like that of the input mentioned in the question and the output which it produces is the same as the output mentioned in the question.

Comment: @HaseebJaved I don't know C++. But that's not a problem. Please clarify your question with a simple example like I did. Then everyone can answer yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy. I will tell you only algorithm.

> 1. Make two [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). One with *value* of all the marks in *exam* and one with all the marks in *lab*. Use *Student ID* as the *key*.
> 2. Now start with first index of each TreeMap and pick the *values*.
>
>    2.1. If both *values* have same *key* then pick the next one else pick both different *key* and remove the  pair from the *maps*.

An example may help. Suppose the scenario is like below

```
Student ID      lab       exam

 1              80         10
 2              50         50
 3              40         70
 4              20         40
```

So after creating TreeMap it will look like

```
labMap      examMap
<K,V>        <K,V>

<1,80>       <3,70>
<2,50>       <2,70>
<3,40>       <4,70>
<4,20>       <1,70>
```

So you can see we will first take 1 and 3.

Then as 2 and 2 is same we will choose 2 and 4.

After 3 and 2.

Atlast 4 and 1.

Comment: You must be psychic, because I have no idea what the question actuallyis

Comment: @boxed__l **NO**. Just two TreeMaps. One for the *lab* and one for the *exam*.

Comment: But I don't get it how this is producing groups of students who complement each other on nay basis. I mean one possible criteria that I can think of is that grouping is done in such a way that the cumulative marks of students in a group in both labs and exams are maximized.

Comment: By *complement* do you mean group student **A** whose mark is **highest** in *lab* with student **B** whose mark is **lowest** in *lab*?

Comment: Yes. That is one way of assuring that each group has maximum commutative marks. May be you should check out the source code of my solution, it might give you more insight. Kindly check the comments on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I try to suggest you a Pareto optimal algorithm:

- build a single tree
- the first node is about choosing the number of groups: for example if you have 10 students you can have a number of groups from 4:  {3,3,2,2} to 5: {2,2,2,2,2}. In this way, in this simple example, the first node has only TWO sons, one with 4 groups and one with 5 groups.
- You start expanding the node with less groups and you generate all possible combinations (without repetitions).
- For example you generate combination {3,3,2,2}. From here you assign in order a student and you generate another node: you start from student s1 { {s1,,}, {,,}, {,}, {,} }, then you add s2: { {s1,s2,}, {,,}, {,}, {,} } etc. Each time you arrive to a final node, you calculate the value of the solution. One example of value could be the sum of the mean difference between groups, differentiated for subject and component (or you can do a weighted sum on lab and exam, if you prefer). For example with two subjects and two components per subject you will have 4 incomparable values. The solution would be something like { *D1*, *D2*, *D3*, *D4*} where the value *Dn* is the average distance between groups on value *n*.
- If a solution is [Pareto optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) or is the only solution available, you add it to the set of feasible solutions. Each time you get a solution you have to compare it's optimality with all the solutions in the solution set. If a solution of the set is *dominated* by this solution, you have to remove it from the set.
- Finally you will have a set of Pareto efficient solutions from which to choose from. The choice can be done by apply some [solution concept](http://multiagent.com/2013/02/game-theory-solution-concepts.html), in this case I would use *social efficiency*, which means to choose from the Pareto frontier the solution which minimizes the sum of differences in the all values. This means `SocialValue = -(*D1*+*D2*+*D3*+*D4*)`. Note the sign minus: it's because you have to maximize `SocialValue`, which is the minimization of the sum of values.